# here is the error about googleSignIn : MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)

Tags: flutter, google-signin

**I got a error when ı trying to continue with googleSignIn**

**I searched everywhere to find a solution even every title in stackoverflow about that have read them and apply what they sad but it seems it's not gonna be solve**

```
E/flutter (18732): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel 
plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
E/flutter (18732): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod 
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (18732): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18732): #1      GoogleSignIn._callMethod 
(package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:233:5)
E/flutter (18732): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18732): #2      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled 
(package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart)
E/flutter (18732): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18732):
```

**Provide with codee as the below**

**Where I want it to show the error with the silently entry I specified in initstate, I first get the error there, then when I click on the google login button, I get the error I added in detail at the beginning, you can follow the code here.**

```
final GoogleSignIn googlegiris = GoogleSignIn();
final bool girdimi=false;
 @override
 void initState() {
   googlegiris.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((googleHesap) {
   setState(() {
     kullaniciKontrol(googleHesap);
    });
   }, onError: (gHata) {
    print("Hata Mesaj: " + gHata.toString());
   });

googlegiris.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((googleHesap2) {
    setState(() {
     kullaniciKontrol(googleHesap2);
    });
     }).catchError((gHata) {
    print("Hata Mesaj 2: " + gHata.toString());
   });
  super.initState();
 }
 kullaniciGiris() {
setState(() {
  googlegiris.signIn();
});
 }

  kullaniciKontrol(GoogleSignInAccount girisHesap) async {
    if (girisHesap != null) {
      await kullaniciFireStoreKayit();
      setState(() {
      girdimi = true;
      });
     } else {
      setState(() {
      girdimi = false;
     });
    }
  }
     kullaniciFireStoreKayit() async {
final GoogleSignInAccount gAnlikKullanici = googlegiris.currentUser;
DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot = await kullaniciRef.doc(gAnlikKullanici.id).get();
if (!documentSnapshot.exists) {
  final username = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HesapOlusturmaSayfasi()));

  kullaniciRef.doc(gAnlikKullanici.id).set({
    "id": gAnlikKullanici.id,
    "profileName": gAnlikKullanici.displayName,
    "username": username,
    "url": gAnlikKullanici.photoUrl,
    "email": gAnlikKullanici.email,
    "biography": "",
    "timestamp": timestamp,
  });
  await takipciRef.doc(anlikKullanici.id).collection("takipciler").doc(anlikKullanici.id).set({});
  documentSnapshot = await kullaniciRef.doc(anlikKullanici.id).get();
}
anlikKullanici = Kullanici.fromDocument(documentSnapshot.data());
    }
    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       if (girdimi == true) {
         return GirisEkran();`enter code here`
        } else {
       return kayitEkrani();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have added the `google_sign_in` package as a dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: yes ı have added already , ı turn on google auth from firebase ı did them

Comment: Also do you have your `google-services.json` file generated and added to your project?

Comment: Yes ı have json file which ı took from firebase

Comment: What platform do you use?. Make sure to implement everything required to run on specific platforms

Comment: I am sorry , Do you mean which language you are coding ? ı am using flutter.

Comment: Are you running on android or iOS?

Comment: ı am running on android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by myself , ı went to this website https://console.cloud.google.com/ and ı have enabled **Google People API** from there with my google account which ı created firestore with . I took this information from https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in in **Android integration.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are on version `google_sign_in 4.1.0` or higher, you should be good to go on web, iOS and Android.

Anything below `4.1.0`, you need to additionally add [`google_sign_in_web`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web) to your *pubspec.yaml*.

**What does this exception mean?**

It is the result of the multiplatform-plugin concept that should be used by Flutter Plugins, called `Federated plugins`, consisting of multiple sub-packages:

1. An interface, every platform must implement
2. The app-package, providing the API that should be used in the flutter application
3. Any other platform implementation

The current platform overrides the current Platform-Interface instance with its implementation.
Please read more about in in the [official Flutter Federated Plugin Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#federated-plugins).

In the case of the *google_sign_in* package, the default implementation is the platform-channel implementation usually used by the mobile apps. On web, a [different implementation](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in_web/lib/google_sign_in_web.dart#L65) is used.

The platform channel exception could therefore occur, because you are on web trying to run it without the web implementation, or on any other platform not having a platform implementation yet (Currently there are only web, iOS and Android implementations). You can check, if a platform is supported on the [plugin page](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in), right under the name: [Sample image for the *google_sign_in package*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBJag.png).

Comment: As you see it google_sign_in 5.0.4 is supporting android , this is not solution to solve my problem ?

Comment: could you provide the code you are running as the error occurs?

Comment: ı edited my post and ı shared my codes which ı take error occurs.